# Get relative middle index from the non-zeros values of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing

I have a vector that starts with zeros then some positive values then again zeros. I want to get the index of the cell located in the middle of the non-zero values. For example, if `A=[0;0;0;2;2;3;5;7;0;0]` then the index of the middle cell will be 3 which has the value 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have just one set of non-zeros values in `A`, you can use two approaches here.

Approach 1 -

```
relative_middle_index = round(numel(nonzeros(A))/2)
```

Approach 2 -

```
relative_middle_index = round(diff(find(diff(A~=0)))/2)
```

You can get the absolute middle indices using two approaches.

Approach 1 -

```
absolute_middle_index = round((find(A~=0,1) + find(A~=0,1,'last'))/2)
```

Approach 2 -

```
absolute_middle_index =  round(mean(find(diff(A~=0))))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and the three approaches :)  could you tell me how to get the index not the value of the middle?

Comment: @user1460166 For getting the index, just use whatever is inside the round brackets - `A(..)`. For getting the index with the second approach, extra code needs to be added. Let me know if you want  that too or if this didn't make sense.

Comment: @user1460166 Use `round((find(A~=0,1) + find(A~=0,1,'last'))/2)` to get the "absolute" index (`6`). Or `(nnz(A)+1)/2` to get the "relative" index (`3`)

Comment: @LuisMendo That `nnz` could be a separate answer! I sort of misinterpreted the question and thought the value is needed, in fact the relative middle index was needed. The title led me that way I guess.

Comment: @user1460166 Updated my solution and sorry I misinterpreted the question as that value there was `3` and also the title suggested the `middle value`.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for your answer, I discovered another issue. I want the middle index in the whole column, not the middle index of the non-zero elements. So if you could please let me know. Thank you very much

Comment: @user1460166 So what would be the expected output using the sample data provided in  the question? I thought it would be `3`.

Comment: @Divakar yes, its correct, but can you in a comment here tell me if I need the index of the middle non-zero value `3` according to the whole column which would be `6`?

Comment: @user1460166 Try this `round(mean(find(diff(A~=0))))`

Comment: @user1460166 Edited solution with it.